# Influence of temperature on protein binding and decay rates

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, molecular-biology, proteins, molecular-genetics

For computer modeling purposes, I am looking for some referenced quantitative measurements of the effect(s) of temperature on the dynamic of biochemical reactions.

**Question**

In particular, my question is:

**How does temperature influences rate of protein binding to a DNA-binding motif?**

---

**I am NOT looking for..**

I am not looking for a theoretical explanation of how temperature influences this process (I have basic understanding of the importance of the activation energy as displayed on a Maxwell-Boltzman distribution and of the michaelis-menten equation).

**I am looking for..**

I am looking for a function (eventually expressing the michaelis-menten constant as a function of the temperature) that I can plug in my algorithms to incorporate the influence of various temperatures on the process I want to simulate. I want to simulate the average gene network from an average standard eukaryote. For other purpose, I chose parameter values coming from the yeast. A index such as the [$Q_{10}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q10_(temperature_coefficient)) would be very useful as well.

**Similar already-answered question**

A similar question (influence of temperature on transcription rate) has been asked and answered (by @rhill45) [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21258/how-does-temperature-influences-rate-of-protein-decay).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do your second one first, you want to find the rate of binding:

Yes you are right you need to calculate for km

I think I found the paper that ties temp into the reaction rate:

statistical approach called response surface methodology (RSM) is used for the prediction of the kinetic constants of glucose oxidase (GOx) as a function of reaction temperature and pH. Lineweaver–Burk transformation of the Michaelis–Menten equation was utilized as the integral part of the RSM algorithm. The effects of variables, namely reciprocal of substrate concentration (0.033–0.5 mM−1), reaction temperature (14.9–40.1 °C) and reaction pH (pH 4.4–8.5) on the reciprocal of initial reaction rate were evaluated and a second order polynomial model was fitted by a central composite circumscribed design (CCCD).

Biochemical Engineering Journal
August 2005, Vol.25(1):55–62, doi:10.1016/j.bej.2005.04.001
A new approach for determination of enzyme kinetic constants using response surface methodology
İsmail Hakkı Boyacı

For the decay

I'm still working on the first I'm suggesting to check this out but need sleep I can read it tomorrow

http://www.eastcoastbio.com/productcart/pc/stability_testing.asp

Comment: Nice. Your article answers my second question (although the article is about enzymatic reaction and not specifically about protein binding). I made the mistake to ask several questions in one post. I restricted this post to one question and checked your answer. [Here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21258/how-does-temperature-influences-rate-of-protein-decay) is the other question. Thanks a lot