# How does Temperature influences the rate of protein turnover?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, proteins, molecular-genetics, transcription

**Question**

How (quantitatively speaking) does temperature influences rate of turnover of transcription factors?

**Which protein?**

As I am not looking for any accurate number I am talking about an "average" transcription factor. I leave to you the choice of answering this question with some very accurate example (Transcription factor GTF II A for example) or with some broad observation on how temperature influences protein turnover.

The organism I'd like to model is a typical unicellular eukaryote such as a yeast for example that lives at "standard" range of temperature (between 5°C and 35°C roughly speaking).

Of course, I am not interested in considering a transcription factor that is directly involved in some response to a change in environmental temperature. I am interested in transcription factors which are involved in developmental pathways that have nothing to do with reaction of the body to temperature.

I am looking for a referenced answer $\ddot \smile$

Comment: See [this answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21258/how-does-temperature-influence-the-rate-of-protein-degradation/24218#24218)

Comment: Would you want to close this question as you can find the answer in the other post?

Comment: That makes you the first person to close their own post :P